# Why is Gilt a word when we have Gilded? Is this town big enough for the both of them?

Tags: history, past-tense

We would never say "I builded my own house", and we would never say "I ment my fences" - as far as I can tell, words either went the d-to-t route, or they went the add-ed route. Gild, for some reason, went both ways. (Progressive, for its time!)

Is there any reason why this word bucked the trend and kept both past tense forms? I've reviewed existing material here on English SE and the interwebs in general and can't find any historical reasoning.

Comment: What is an interweb? There are many existing pairs such as you describe, such as *learned* and *learnt*, *leaned* and *leant*, etc.

Comment: @tchrist A common misspelling of _an intarwebz_.

Comment: @tchrist I've never seen learnt and lent used legitimately (in that context. I've obviously seen lent as loaned or as a religious holiday). I have occasionally seen both gilded and gilt, though.

Comment: You have never seen *learnt* used “legitimately”?  Nor *leant* either? Really?? I completely disbelieve you. Go check your winterebby thingy for both of them.  Use the store-boughten version not the home-made one while you’re at it.

Comment: The words are different parts of speech. *Gilt* is an adjective, and *gilded* is the verbal participle. You don't say "I gilt this" just as you don't say "I ment this". What is there here that a dictionary does not tell you? [gild/gilded](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gild) | [gilt](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/gilt)

Comment: @AndrewLeach _Gilt_ is an adjective that derives from a past participle (which, of course, _is_ an adjective). _Gilded_ is the past participle and (it seems, though I’m not entirely sure) the older form. So why did the alternative past participle not only appear, but become limited to the adjective, unlike the entirely parallel _learnt_, _built_, etc.?

Comment: @Andrew Leach Their adjectival usages _do_ overlap. ([OLD](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/gilded) :gilded (adjective) ). Like the usages of gold and golden, wood and wooden, wool and woollen; those of some flat and regular adverbs, ...

Comment: @EdwinAshworth _Gold(en)/wood(en)/wool(len)_ overlap, but differ from _gilded/gilt_ by one of them being simply a perfectly regular adjunctive use of the noun. _Gilded/gilt_ are historically identical in morphological derivation, mean the same thing, but are distinct nonetheless. The only real parallel I can think of is _bend_, whose normal past participle is _bent_, except in the phrase _on **bended** knee_. Perhaps unsurprisingly, that one has a root that ends in continuant + _d_ as well. Even _girt/girded_ is not a parallel, because those two are completely interchangeable.

Comment: @Janus The juries are out on the word classes of say glass, plastic, wood, wool, gold used attributively. The online dictionaries are even self-inconsistent when dealing with these attributive-nouns-showing-material v derived adjectives. Conversion is a well known phenomenon; who decides when it has taken place is less well known.

Comment: @choster Kind of, but not really. That question seems to reinforce my point that each 'dual word' has a history behind it. It is that history that I'm looking for in this question, which would never be addressed by that question.

Comment: 'Speeded' and 'sped' intrigue me. I'd choose 'He speeded up as soon as he left the outskirts of the town, and sped up the road leading into the hills.' 'Bent' and 'bended' are not usually interchanged, though 'burned' and 'burnt' are. 'Set' is the normal past, but 'setted' for 'put into sets'.

Comment: In all honesty, Edwin, I only hear "speeded" from schoolchildren and I never hear "bended". I will admit to having heard "burnt" and "burned" - usually, "burnt" when describing food and "burned" for everything else. I bet that has an interesting history just like Gild.

Comment: @corsiKa You've never heard the phrase _(down) on bended knee_? That is the only place where this form is used—but the phrase is **never** used with the form _bent_, at least not in my experience.

Answer (score 3):

Allow me to begin with a bit of a red herring before coming to partial answers.

It would be natural to assume that the case of *gilded/gilt* is parallel to the case of *burned/burnt*. In the latter case, these phenomena play together:

- The inclination to regularise verb forms.
- The reluctance to change the spelling of adjectives.
- The fact that in this case the US is more progressive than the UK.

The result is as follows, according to data from the Google Ngram Viewer:

- BE has only a slight preference for *burned* when used unambiguously as a verb form, and at the beginning of the century there was actually still a slight preference for *burnt* even in this context. For attributive use, *burnt* is still twice as common as *burned* in BE.
- AE prefers *burned* for clear verb form use since the middle of the 19th century. Since the early 20th century it no longer prefers *burnt* for attributive use - the two forms are about equally common in this context now.

(Search strings used: "have_INF burned,have_INF burnt" vs. "_DET_ burned _NOUN_,_DET_ burnt _NOUN_".)

Surprisingly, the data for *gilded/gilt* is much weaker than for *burned/burnt*.

- *Gilded* is consistently about twice as common as *gilt* for attributive use. (The factor is only slightly more than 2 in AE and only slightly less in BE.)
- Unsurprisingly, both variants of English also prefer *gilded* over *gilt* when it is unambiguously a verb form (after a form of *have*), and this preference is stronger in AE than in BE. But surprisingly, this preference is *weaker* than for attributive use. Even more surprisingly, in BE the specific phrase *having gilt* is a special exception in that it is several times more common than *having gilded*!

Fortunately I found the solution to the last mystery: The vast majority of occurrences of *having gilt* in recent British literature is actually in the exact phrase "having gilt the ocean with his beams" from Shakespeare's Titus Andronicus.

A similarly strong distortion is caused by *gilt edges* (never: *gilded edges*) of books. As these were once mentioned so often in catalogues, they tended to dominate attributive use of *gilded/gilt* for many decades.

Finally, I didn't use it at first because I have no idea how it's implemented, but you can also use the ngram viewer to search for *gilded/gilt* as an adjective as opposed to *gilded/gilt* as a verb form ("gilded_ADJ,gilt_ADJ"). The result is for once actually consistent with the above results for *burned/burnt*:

As adjectives, *gilded* and *gilt* are about equally common right now, but until very recently (about 1990), *gilt* was about twice as common as *gilded*. The irregular form is only slightly more common in BE than in AE.

**Conclusion:** Ultimately it looks as if, similar to the case of *burnt*, the main reason for the inertia of *gilt* is those cases where it is felt to be an adjective rather than a verb form, gilt edges of books perhaps being the most important.

**PS:** I just noticed that your question starts with a misunderstanding of language evolution. It's not that every verb went one route or another. A lot of verbs went both routes and then the two forms battled it out between them. Overall, from some point on *-ed* was considered to be the normal, regular past participle ending. But there seems to have been a phase in the 19th century during which the *-t* endings appeared to be winning.

What we need to look for, and I have done this above as well as I could, is reasons to prefer one (e.g. regularity) or the other (e.g. tradition), as well as factors that make one or the other of these reasons stronger.